# Can WebView2 currently receive Keyboard inputs

Tags: wpf, on-screen-keyboard, webview2

I am trying to create a software in WPF which hosts a browser (WebView2 currently 1.0.818.41) and also show a OnScreenKeyboard when there is a input field focused in the browser.

I have done this kind of stuff with CefSharp in WPF before but I cannot do it with WebView2 currently. My problem is I do not find a way to send keystrokes from the OnScreenKeyboard (or from the WPF Window) to the Browser.

In CefSharp there we have a function called **ChromiumWebBrowser.GetHost().SendKeyEvent()** but I cannot find something similar in WebView2.

Am I blind or is this something which is currently not implemented (or maybe not planed)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the 'keyboard' clicked (on the letter) and then you want to send the key to your program? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes the 'keyboard' in my application is clicked and than I want the browser (in the same application) -> just another control to show this clicked key in the current focused input element.

If the term keyboard is missleading than just think about two controls in one WPF application. One Control is the WebView2 and the other control is just a button.

When the button is clicked I want to show some value in the focused element of the WebView2 control. Lets say WebView2 is showing the google page than I want to show the value in the search bar.

I hope this makes it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way. What can be done is execute some JS, which in turn posts a message to WebView. This message can then be caught back in `wv2_WebMessageReceived` event.

There is extensive documentation on the interop between.NET and JS and interop between JS and .NET WPF Forms [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Jan/14/Taking-the-new-Chromium-WebView2-Control-for-a-Spin-in-NET-Part-1).

A solution would be to inject a `sendMessage` JS function in the `NavigationStarting` event:

```js
private void wv2_NavigationStarting(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2 sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs args){
var sc = "function sendMessage(txt) { window.chrome.webview.postMessage(txt); }";
            wv2.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(sc);
        }
```

Now you collect input fields and add `onfocus` and `onblur` events to these input fields for example in the `NavigationCompleted` event like this:

```js
private void wv2_NavigationCompleted(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2 sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args){
     string script = "const collection ="+ 
                 "document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\");" +
                 "for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){" +
                 "collection[i].onfocus= ()=>{ sendMessage('onFocus('+collection[i].name')'); }; " +
                 "collection[i].onblur= (ev)=>{ sendMessage('onBlur('+collection[i].name')'); };"+
                 "}";
     sender.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
}
```

Now catch the message in the `wv2_WebMessageReceived` event:

```js
private void wv2_WebMessageReceived(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2 sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            var postMess = args.TryGetWebMessageAsString();
            
            if (postMess == "onFocus(nameOfField)" )
            {
                // here activate the button(keyboard)
                 // store the Name on focusField variable

            }
            if (postMess == "onBlur" && paneShown)
            {
               // here deactivate the button(keyboard)
                // release the focusField

            }
        }
```

Now you can send a click event to the input fields:

```
private void btn_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var script = "var field "+
                         "= document.getElementsByName("+focusField+");" +
                         " field.value+=field.value"+args.keyValue();
             wv2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
        }
```

`wv2` is an instance of `WebView2` and the code is typed directly here and not compiled. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hi, in the meantime I have implemented this with CefSharp, but thank you for your explanation. I have not tried it but I think this can work as you described, so I will mark your answer as solution.