# WinUI 3 + WebView2: On-screen keyboard does not appear

Tags: winui-3, webview2, on-screen-keyboard

I am creating an application in WinUI 3 with WebView2 according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui) example. It has some user interface and space to display web pages. The app will run on a kiosk without a keyboard and mouse, just a touch screen. As OSK we use the proven [Hot Virtual Keyboard](https://hotvirtualkeyboard.com/).

The problem is that the keyboard is only displayed when entering the TextBox, but not when entering the input of the web page in the WebView2 control. In the Edge browser itself, in web pages, the keyboard displays well.

Developed on Windows 10
Running on Windows 11

I found similar questions, but they were all related to WPF applications and not to WinUI 3, and the solutions were not relevant.

Comment: I believe these similar questions can be very related, as in both cases the problems stems  from the fact that WebView2 is embedded in an app.  Please check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71710225/383426

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.